# How many irreducible representations are there in a cyclic group?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups

$$
  \begin{array}{c|c|c|}
      \backslash
    & e
    & p
    \\
    \hline
      e
    & e
    & p
    \\
    \hline
      p
    & p
    & e
    \\
    \hline
  \end{array}
$$
(Original picture of the table [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjUEz.jpg).)

First I want to look at the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_2$. In this group, the symmetric functions transform under the trivial representation ($D(e) = D(p) = 1$, so all group actions do nothing to the function), and the antisymmetric functions transform under the sign representation ($D(e) = 1, D(p) = -1$, so we need to act $D(p)$ twice to get the orignal function, acting once won't do). There are two irreducible representarion, and they all create their own subspace. All nice and dandy.

$$
  \begin{array}{c|c|c|c|}
      \backslash
    & e
    & a
    & b
    \\
    \hline
      e
    & e
    & a
    & b
    \\
    \hline
      a
    & a
    & b
    & e
    \\
    \hline
      b
    & b
    & e
    & a
    \\
    \hline
  \end{array}
$$
(Original picture of the table [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buSyP.jpg).)

But what I don't understand is the group $\mathbb{Z}_3$, because it seems to me that they only create two irreducible representation also, whereas it should be three. Nothing wrong with the trivial representation subspace, but the two remaining representation:

1. $D(a) = e^{2\pi i/3}$, $D(b) = e^{4\pi i/3}$
2. $D(a) = e^{4\pi i/3}$, $D(b) = e^{2\pi i/3}$

seems indistinguishable. An "antisymmetric" function need $D(a)$ or $D(b)$ to act thrice to return to the original function, in both representation; and $D(a)D(b)$ or $D(b)D(a)$ also return the original function, in both representation.

So what did I misunderstand here? Are there only two irreducible representations? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is that you are right if you are talking about real representations (indeed there are only two real irreducible representation of $\mathbb{Z}_3$. But the non trivial one is the $\frac{2 \cdot \pi}{3}$ rotation (which is isomorphic to the $\frac{4 \cdot \pi}{3}$ rotation) in $\mathbb{R}^2$, so its dimension is $2$).

But, since you are using complex numbers, I think you mean complex representations.

In this case the two representation (let me call them $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ with $\rho_i : \mathbb{Z}_3 \to GL_1(\mathbb{C}) \cong \mathbb{C}$ ) are not isomorphic because there is no $\mathbb{C}-$linear invertible function $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ (maybe your confusion is here, you seem to be looking at $\mathbb{R}-$linear functions) such that $f( \rho_1(a)z) = \rho_2(a)( f(z))$ for any $a \in \mathbb{Z}_3$ and $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

This fact is indeed true because since $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is $\mathbb{C}-$linear and invertible, there exist $\lambda \neq 0$ such that $f(z) = \lambda z$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$. 
Let $\omega = e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}$, then for $a = [1]$ we have $ \rho_1(a)(z) = \omega z$ and $\rho_2(a)(z) = \omega^2 z$.
Now, the equation implies $\lambda \omega z = \lambda \omega^2 z$ for any $z \in \mathbb{C}$, which is absurd (because $\lambda \neq 0$).

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Wouldn't $f=e^{2 \pi I/3}$ work? No?

Comment: No it doesn't, since then $LHS = e^{\frac{4\pi i}{3}}z \neq z = RHS$ (considering the right value of $a$ given which one is $\rho_i$ for $i=1,2$)

Comment: Oh year sorry. I misread an a as b in your answer. BUt is there a proof for the inexistence of the $f$ function? I'm just curious.

Comment: I am editing my post with it

Comment: @LucaMac Hi. I still don't understand the logic. I have been asked to classify all non-isomorphic simple $C_3$-module which is similar, but how do I translate the language? What I do: Let $C_3=\{e,g,g^2\}$ and $V$ be the module. I know $V$ should be one dimensional, hence $V=span\{v\}$ for some $v\in V$. The $C_3$ acts on $V$, so we should have $g.v$=$kv$ for some complex number $k$. What is next? I have no idea what we are going to do. Thank you for the guidance.